# downloaded zip file contains another zip file inside it, but should not (PHP)

Tags: php

I created a zipped log file created in non-web accessible directory.

I can open the zip, looks perfect.  Contains only the foo.log file entry.

However, when I download the zip file the zip contains within it another zip file and that one contains the foo.log entry.

using this to download:

$file is name of the zip file ie basename($full_path_to_zip)

```
147         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
148         header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
149         header('Content-Type: application/zip');
150         header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
151         header('Expires: 0');
152         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
153         header('Pragma: public');
154         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path_to_zip));
155         ob_clean();
156         flush();
157         readfile($full_path_to_zip);
158         exit();
```

Wuts up?

So the downloaded zip is target.zip, this is what I see

"target.zip" -> contains "target" (also a zip) -> contains "foo.log"

where I used quotes to denote the actual file names.

Comment: PHP will not "zip up" a file inside another zip all on its own. If you're getting zipped-zips, then YOU are generating that. As well, You're issuing TWO content-types, which is pointless. You're essentially saying "This file is an elephant AND a pineapple". A file can only have ONE mime-type, and your `app/zip` mime-type will overwrite/replace the app/octet-stream one.

Comment: More info...no I'm not zipping them on the download, they were already zipped.  On Windoze system the downloaded zip is completely corrupt and will not open.  I made a zip using my OS (Debian 7), not php, opened it verified it works perfect, dragged that to web server folder.  Extracted just the download PHP code into a new php file, made it download the zip I created by hand.  Looks good but when I open it (meaning I see the one file name it should contain), but the contents are corrupt.

Comment: OK here's the answer:

If ob_clean() is present (line 155 of original question) the downloaded zip file is corrupt even if no ob_start() was ever called.  I have two choices:

1. put ob_end_clean() before starting download
2. remove the ob_clean() statement

I'm going with 2nd option.

I got the ob_clean() from readfile() page right at php.net, serves me right for copy/pasting code!